# Azure DevOps: Limit possible Approvers

Tags: azure-devops

When creating a pull request, I can add any person as reviewer. How can I enforce that the reviewer comes from a defined team?

I know the "Automatically included reviewers" option (see picture bellow) where everyone from a selected team could review but I simply want to restrict the reviewers which the committer can select.

I foresee a `team "lead developers"` and the pull requester has to `select one of them as reviewer`.

[image]

Comment: I suggest creating a group  "Leads" on the lines of your suggestion which is added in Branch policy as Required. And Add one more policy - Minimum number of reviewers to be 1 and in both policy do not allow requester to approve their changes. This was only one the Leads can approve it

Comment: When adding them as Required, all of them will receive a notification: Hence I want that only one of them can be selected when creating the pull request

Comment: You cannot limit which users that can be added to pull requests as reviewers. @scorpio's answer is the correct way. I suggest disabling email notifications if that is an issue, but it might not work in your use case.

Comment: Please, add that as answer so that i can accept